# Substraction column to another column of next row in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to calculate the subtraction of c= b-a, and d= b2-a3... How can I do that?

```
name    a   b   c=b-a   d=b2-a3…
peter   80  100 20      30
dancy   70  90  20      20
tiger   70  85  15      20
pop     85  101 16      29
rock    72  111 39
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss8vC.png)
Thank you so much!

Comment: For `c`: `YourDataframe$c <- with(YourDataframe, b-a)`

Comment: for `d`: `YourDataframe$d <- with(YourDataframe, b - c(tail(a, -1), NA))`

Comment: if this is the answer, why is it between the comments?

Comment: @Edo https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments For me the code is to basic. If you want you can produce an answer from my comments.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming your data is in a dataframe, to recreate your column using a tidyverse approach you could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

yourdata <- yourdata %>% 
mutate(c = b - a, 
       d = b - lead(a))
```

To do the opposite you can use lag, to increase the number of steps in either lag or lead you can use lag(column_name, n = number of steps).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, c := b - a][, d := b - shift(a, type = 'lead')]
```

Comment: `[, ':='(c= b-a, d= b - shift(a, type = 'lead'))]`